# How to mount PS3 Blu-ray discs on Windows 7 (or any OS/Blu-ray drive)?

Tags: filesystems, mount, blu-ray, disc

I have a BD-drive (Blu-ray disc drive) and I would like to mount the filesystem used by the disc, however, nothing happens when inserted. My BD-drive doesn't even report that anything's there, from the perspective of the device driver, I presume.

Is this a filesystem issue (do PS3 discs use special filesystems)?

I just want to see what's on the disc (like files and stuffs). What is preventing my Blu-ray drive from working with the disc, and why can't the BD-drive driver report the info to the GUI?

I would be thankful if the whole entire technical scoop on what the problem might be is explained, and it would be appreciated if someone can describe it for the benefit of all who may wish to do something similar to this.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe You can't do it without ripping it protection first:

> BD-ROM Mark is a small amount of cryptographic data that is stored
>   separately from normal Blu-ray Disc data, aiming to prevent
>   replication of the discs. The cryptographic data is needed to decrypt
>   the copyrighted disc content protected by AACS.[175] A specially
>   licensed piece of hardware is required to insert the ROM-Mark into the
>   media during mastering. During replication, this ROM Mark is
>   transferred together with the recorded data to the disc. In
>   consequence, any copies of a disc made with a regular recorder will
>   lack the ROM-Mark data, and **will be unreadable on standard players.**

Comment: That's not it. BD-ROM Marked discs are normally readable by all BD drives. In fact, Every copyrighted disc, like movie, will have it.

Comment: "In consequence, **any copies** of a disc made with a regular recorder will lack the ROM-Mark data, and will be unreadable on standard players." The question isn't about copies.

Answer (score 0):

Console discs always used to be proprietary formatted (PS2, PS3, WII, XBOX), as one of anti-piracy measures. Your blu-ray drive expects to see some kind of "catalogue" of files or folders on that disc, which should be there and begin in standard place, if it adhered to BD standard, but it isn't for reason stated above. It could be somewhere else on the disc and have proprietary format which normal BD drives have no way of understanding. Console drives have special firmware or even chips on them that allow them to read these discs.

People who wished to copy PS3 BD discs already found a way, but they're not on Superuser, or at least do not ask about it here.